# Calendar control for Windows Phone 7?

Tags: windows-phone-7, calendar

Is there a calendar control available for WP7 (not the datepicker and timepicker)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I also started new project on CodePlex.  Just published alpha version of calendar control that I have been working on for a bit.  http://wpcontrols.codeplex.com/
Sergey

Answer (score 3):

Mick,  thanks for the response.

Found this calendar control on CodePlex.  This was just posted today :)
http://calendarcontrolwp7.codeplex.com/

Looking into it now!
Pratik

Answer (score 0):

There is no calendar control built in.

Answer (score 0):

Telerik controls for Windows Phone now include a calendar control.  I have a license so I should be able to use those controls.